# set flash mode camera.parameters android 4.0.3 on Asus Transformer TF101G

Tags: android, android-camera

My app sets the flash-mode parameter of android camera to off. 
This is the code:

```
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
params.set("flash-mode", "off");
camera.setParameters(params);
```

It correctly works on Asus Transformer TF101G with android version 3.2 or minor, but with ICS (4.0.3) the app crashes with this error on logcat:

```
05-28 22:38:12.754 V/NvOmxCameraSettingsParser(   98): Changed: flash-mode: (null) -> off {(null)}
05-28 22:38:12.754 E/NvOmxCameraSettingsParser(   98): Failed substring capabilities check, unsupported parameter: 'off', original: (null) 
05-28 22:38:12.754 E/NvOmxCameraSettingsParser(   98): extractChanges: Invalid parameter!
05-28 22:38:12.754 E/NvOmxCamera(   98): setParameters: Invalid parameters
05-28 22:38:12.754 W/Checkwin( 2066): Unexpected error initializating camera
05-28 22:38:12.754 W/Checkwin( 2066): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
05-28 22:38:12.754 W/Checkwin( 2066):   at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
05-28 22:38:12.754 W/Checkwin( 2066):   at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1297)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
```

and camera.setParameters(params);

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because Asus Transformer TF101G doesn't have the flashlight.